# Breaking each loop after 5 clones

Tags: javascript

How can i break the loop after it clones 5 times?

```
            $('track', xml).each(function() {
                c = $('.playlist:first').css({
                    display: 'none'
                }).clone();
                $(c).find('.cover img').attr('src', $(this).find('cover').text().trim());
                $(c).find('.artist').html($(this).find('artist').text().trim());
                $(c).find('.title').html($(this).find('title').text().trim());
                $(c).find('.time').html($(this).find('time').text().trim());
                c = rfm.lazyload.convert(c);
                $('.playlist:last').after(c);
                $('.playlist:last').css({
                    display: 'inline-block'
                });
            });
```

I really dont know how to do it, help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`slice`](https://api.jquery.com/slice/):

```
$('track', xml).slice(0,5).each(function() {
```